# Does running MW2 means you can run MW3?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

I read somewhere that MW2 and MW3 share the same core. But the system requirements are a bit different. Does this means that if I can run very smoothly MW2, I can run smoothly MW3 on the same computer?

For example, my Pentium 4 3.2 ghz, 3GB ram, with ATI HD 2400 PRO 512MB runs very smoothly MW2, does this means I'll run smoothly MW3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MW3 has a couple more tricks up the sleeve to look handsome, but, yes, in principle, you should be able to run MW3 as smooth as you can run MW2.

You just might have to turn down a few settings, but the overall experience will most probably stay the same.

Comment: I just noticed I run smoothly mw2 on res 640x480. Will I still run MW3?

Comment: Smooth is relative - but being so much on the edge, it might not run at all..

Comment: [canyourunit](http://canyourunit.com)